# Can this do-able using regular expressions patterns (capture groups)?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

In JS, I have a set of strings that need to break down into an array. Each string can be breakdown up to 5 groups (Some have less). I'm using regex to break all.

In the below string sets if it includes `aa` `bb` or`cc` it needs to go into the capture group2.

Im not very familiar with regex unfortunately and stuck at this point.

Is this pattern doable only using regex or do I have to break the from `::` to `|` and explode it later?

My regex pattern `^[ \t]*(?:(?:(\w+)\|)?(?:(\w+):(?:(\w+):)?)?)?(\w+)::(\w+)$` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jFPbsQ/1)

String sets (each line run on a loop in JS):

```
                 group4::group5
              aa:group4::group5
              bb:group4::group5
              cc:group4::group5
          group1|group4::group5
       group1|aa:group4::group5

          group3:group4::group5
       aa:group3:group4::group5
   group1|group3:group4::group5
group1|aa:group3:group4::group5
```

Final results should be able to produce this...

```
var groups = {1:"group1", 2:"group2", 3:"group3", 4:"group4", 5:"group5"};
```

Regex pattern would be sufficient if anyone can help me on this

Comment: Is there something specific in the way that `|` works as opposed to `:`?

Comment: Always group5, group4 exist. `|` character used to separate something special, however, if the pattern is not possible that can be replaced by a `:` (If that helps).

Comment: I believe the most efficient and possible way is to capture whole group and check for 3 values and named them. So that's also an option here. I'm not very good at regex. That's why I'm stuck on this.

Comment: Perhaps not using regex would be a better option then?

Comment: In `group2:group4::group5` why should `group2` not be captured in group #3? And why is it different from `group3:group4::group5`?

Comment: Previosly i had `/(?:([^:|\s]*)\|)?(?:([^:|\s]*):)?([^:|\s]*)::([^:|\s]*)/gm` this pattern (compared with first four sets only), which worked well. then the string sets needed another parameter so I had to match it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this PCRE regex comprising a **branch reset group**, 5 separate capture groups, few optional matches and non-capturing groups:

```sh
^\h*(?:(?:(\w+)\|)?(?|(?:(aa|bb|cc):(?:(\w+):)?)|(?:((?2)):)?(\w+):)?)?(\w+)::(\w+)$
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jFPbsQ/4)

PS: branch reset group doesn't work in Javascript.

Comment: `group3:group4::group5` and `group1|group3:group4::group5` isnt matching correctly on this pattern.

Comment: Clarify case of `group3:group4::group5` and `group2:group4::group5`. Why should they be different?

Comment: Also `group1|group3:group4::group5` is SAME AS `group1|group2:group4::group5` (part of demo) which is already being handled correctly.

Comment: Will you be able to solve it if  `group2` has predefined string sets (example aa, bb, cc)? So check if those are exist put it to group 2, otherwise to group 3?

Comment: Any change in requirement should be part of the question please.

Comment: I just updated the question NEW DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/jFPbsQ/1/

Comment: Awesome! It worked !!! Woohooo... Thanks a lot. You are a truely genius. I'm always bad at regex patterns.

Comment: It worked ! But I'm curious if there any way to do it purely on JS ?

Comment: It is possible in JS but group numbers will be different. Just replace `(?|` with `(?:`

Comment: While I was coding the rest, I found a really wired bug, If the string started by letter `h`, This pattern omits it. https://jsfiddle.net/kL5304po/

Comment: `\h` is for PCRE only. In JS it should be replaced with `[ \t]`